# DataInputStream read(byte[] buffer) is returned irrelevant data

Tags: android, sockets, inputstream, outputstream

How to receive original content and file name from server side code.
Client Code

```
public void send1(Socket socket)
{
    try
    {
        dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + "temp.txt");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

        //write file length
        dataOutputStream.writeLong(file.length());
        Log.i("File Size", "" + file.length());

        //write file names
        dataOutputStream.writeUTF(file.getName());
        Log.i("File Name", "" + file.getName());

        //write file to dos
        byte[] buf = new byte[4092];
        int n = 0;
        while((n = fis.read(buf)) != -1)
        {
            Log.i("length bytes", "" + n);
            dataOutputStream.write(buf, 0, n);
        }

        dataOutputStream.flush();
        dataOutputStream.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

File Name as `temp.txt` and Content as `Hello`

Server Code

```
public void receive1(Socket socket)
{
    try
    {
        inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + "test.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

        int n = 0;
        byte[] buf = new byte[4092];

        //read file name
        /*String fileName = "";
        try
        {
            fileName = dataInputStream.readUTF();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("File Name", "" + fileName);*/

        //read file size
        long fileSize = 0;
        try
        {
            fileSize = dataInputStream.readLong();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("File Size", "" + fileSize);

        //read file
        while((n = dataInputStream.read(buf)) != -1)
        {
            Log.i("length bytes", "" + n);
            fos.write(buf, 0, n);
        }

        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

File Name as `test.txt` and Content as `temp.txtHello`.
In this `test.txt` file, contains `temp.txt`. I am not getting file name from `dataInputStream.readUTF()`.

Where I mistaken code...

If I called `readUTF()` method, then I am getting the Exception

Exception as

```
java.io.EOFException
at libcore.io.Streams.readFully(Streams.java:83)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:99)
at java.io.DataInputStream.decodeUTF(DataInputStream.java:178)
at java.io.DataInputStream.decodeUTF(DataInputStream.java:173)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:169)
```

Comment: You aren't *calling* readUTF(), except in commented-out code. What did you expect?

Comment: @EJB If i called readUTF(), i am getting `java.io.EOFException`

Comment: Suppose you post the real code, and the real exception?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote the `Long` before the `String` in the inputStream of the  send method. What you did in the server code is that you are expecting to recieve String before the Long which in reserved on what you did in your send method.

**solution:**

switch reading long first then string

**sample:**

```
     //read file size
        long fileSize = 0;
        try
        {
            fileSize = dataInputStream.readLong();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("File Size", "" + fileSize);

//read file name
        String fileName = "";
        try
        {
            fileName = dataInputStream.readUTF();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("File Name", "" + fileName);
```

Comment: Hi If i did this one, I am getting `java.io.EOFException` and the file content also empty.

Comment: @SathishSathish post it